# Azure app service only accessible behind API Management

Tags: azure

I'm looking for a way to host a Azure app service behind the Azure API Management without exposing a public url to the app service it self.

The API Management is going to do AD Auth so unauthorized requests are not reaching the app service and waist resources. Same goes for DDos Attacks. Must be terminated by the API Management.

How can I do this? Is the expensive Azure app service environment the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the access to your App service to the ip/hostname of the API Management instance. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions

Ddos is hard because what is desired behavior and what is not proberbly depends if the structure of you APIs. But you could limit each subscription key with a limit. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/transform-api#protect-an-api-by-adding-rate-limit-policy-throttling